# Amcharts adding bullets to axis range

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a problem with bullets. I would like to add bullets above or below of the range, which I will set my own. Unfortunally I didn't find a solution and I came up with an idea to add next series, which will be hidden and I can add to it bullets that I need. I'm wondering if I can filter data on bullets for the first series without adding the second series. Generally, I would like to know if I can filter bullets.

Answer (score 0):

In amcharts 4 exists axis bullets as you can see in this code:

[https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/RXREJV](http://%20%20%20%20https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/RXREJV)

But from what I understood you want something like this:
[image]

As you can find in here:
https://doc.cuba-platform.com/charts-6.7/charts.html